# Can you identify this white, blue, and green train body?

Tags: set-identification

Got that is a bag of parts. For some reason one part of train (it look like train to me) is upside-down by direction of stubs. Browsed through all 4 hundred sets by searching for 'train' on Bricklink but had not spotted that one.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know much about LEGO, but that what you show in the photo looks like an airplane to me. Perhaps I'm right, perhaps I'm wrong.

Edit:

It's from [A.I.R. Operations HQ (4620)](https://brickset.com/sets/4620-1/AIR-Operations-HQ).

[image: 4620 set photo]

Comment: Yep, look like you are right. Similar although with different coloring https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4619-1&name=A.I.R. Patrol Jet

Comment: found the one with right colors - it's from https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4620-1#T=P

Comment: Thanks for your contributions, and welcome to Bricks.SE! I've edited this answer to be more complete based on the info from @AlexeiMartianov comments.